# Why Flutter "await" doesn't wait?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm working on a Flutter app which needs uploading image files to Firebase Storage and then saving urls to Firestore.

Below is my code:

```
void onSubmit() async {
  final fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  //picList has one element.
  List<String> picUrlList = [];

  picList.forEach((element) async {
    //picUrlList.add(await uploadImage(File(element)));
    var url = await uploadImage(File(element));
    picUrlList.add(url);
    print('1');
  });

  await fireStore.collection('xxx').doc('yyy').update({
    "picUrlList": FieldValue.delete(),
  });
  await fireStore.collection('xxx').doc('yyy').update({
    "picUrlList": FieldValue.arrayUnion(picUrlList),
  });
  print('2');
  print(picUrlList.length);

  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditPost()),
    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
  );
}

Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile) async {
  //var uuid = Uuid().v1();
  Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(
      user.uid +  DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + '.jpg');
  await ref.putFile(imageFile);
  return await ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

I was expecting print('1') to be executed before print('2'). But the printout order is 2, 0, 1.

0 is the length of the list, which I hope can be full of urls just added.

I just don't know what's wrong with the code. Somebody help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be executed normally till the end and then the callbacks from `forEach` will start executing, so solve this you have two solutions:

1. Replace `forEach` by `for` loop
2. Use `await Future.forEach(picList, (element) async { var url = await uploadImage(File(element));... });`

Comment: I replaced forEach by for loop and it worked. Thank you so much.  Can you explain why is forEach different than for loop in this situation?